# Javascript regex to match strings with non mixed unicode ranges of characters

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I would like some help regarding a regular expression in Javascript.

I am trying to match any string that contains either only Basic Latin (ASCII) characters or only Greek Unicode characters. Not allowing strings with mixed characters from these two sets.

I have this regular expression which matches the exact opposite (all strings that contain at least one greek and one latin character), but cannot find a way to negate this:

https://regex101.com/r/JHzmhc/1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean any ASCII and Greek?

Comment: Yes, Basic Latin == ASCII, right?

Comment: When you say "Latin", it sounds as if you want to match (or not match) *letters*. When you use `\x00-\x7F`, you match the whole ASCII table chars, thus, it is more appropriate to name those chars *ASCII* chars.

Comment: Edited the question based on your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "The [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block" would be the most formal and precise name, though Unicode documentation is littered with references to ASCII and 0-9 are called the ASCII Digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[\u0000-\u007F]+|[\u0370-\u03FF]+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BKm2PT/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` -  start of a non-capturing group (so that the anchors could be applied to both the altetnatives):

  - `[\u0000-\u007F]+` - 1+ ASCII chars
  - `|` - or
  - `[\u0370-\u03FF]+` - 1+ Greek chars
- `)`  - end of group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: No, I would like to match strings that contain either only ASCII characters or only Greek characters. Not allowing strings with mixed characters from these two sets.

Comment: @ktsangop Ok, now it is clearer. I think this requirement should be added to the question (and replace the dubious one).

Comment: @ktsangop, remember to accept this as the answer if you found it useful. (Edit: sorry, you probably already knew, I saw your low rep and assumed you were new here.)

Comment: Unfortunately `[\u0370-\u03FF]` is insufficient to match all symbols used in the Greek script. If you need to match all Greek symbols rather than an arbitrary (?) subset, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44716799/96656).

Comment: @MathiasBynens: From what I understand, OP needs to only find [Greek & Coptic](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0370-03FF) chars.

Comment: Yeah, those aren’t all of them.

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktor’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701563/96656) has the correct general format. Unfortunately, matching Greek symbols isn’t as simple as `[\u0370-\u03FF]` — that way you miss out on many Greek symbols.

With [Unicode property escapes in regular expressions](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-unicode-property-escapes), you’d do:

```
/^(?:[\0-\x7F\p]+|\p{Script_Extensions=Greek}+)$/u
```

Until Unicode property escapes are officially supported in ECMAScript and implemented everywhere, we can [transpile](https://mothereff.in/regexpu#input=%2F%5E%28%3F%3A%5B%5C0-%5Cx7F%5Cp%5D%2B%7C%5Cp%7BScript_Extensions%3DGreek%7D%2B%29%24%2Fu&unicodePropertyEscape=1) this to:

```
/^(?:[\0-\x7F]+|(?:[\u0342\u0345\u0370-\u0373\u0375-\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0384\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03E1\u03F0-\u03FF\u1D26-\u1D2A\u1D5D-\u1D61\u1D66-\u1D6A\u1DBF-\u1DC1\u1F00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FDD-\u1FEF\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFE\u2126\uAB65]|\uD800[\uDD40-\uDD8E\uDDA0]|\uD834[\uDE00-\uDE45])+)$/
```

Here’s the demo: https://regex101.com/r/cmNTLA/1

Comment: I wasn't really aiming to find something so detailed! My main concern was to be able to target two separate language alphabets and prevent user input that has mixed characters from both languages/unicode sets. Anyway thank you for being precise, it's always nice to learn something new!